# Can I get advice to find a file from .phtml?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to understand Magento platform but I can't locate my file to make changes to an about me section. Can someone help me understand where to look for this file?

```
<?php
/**
 * Blog sidebar custom HTML template
*
* @var $block \Magefan\Blog\Block\Sidebar\Search
*/
?>
<?php $conetnt = $block->getContent() ?>
<?php if ($conetnt) { ?>
<div class="widget block blog-custom" >
    <?php /* without html encode */ ?>
    <?= $conetnt ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It mentions the class of the block on line 5, namely `\Magefan\Blog\Block\Sidebar\Search`.
Locate it in the app/code folder.

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching up the widget block blog-custom and felt so lost.